# Are the heaven of the children (who die) the same as the main Jannah who Momenin go? (Shia view)

Tags: shiism, islamic-basis, jannah, children

I have heard that children won't go to the heaven which Mo'menin (believers) will go (I mean the children who die before the age of puberty). In truth, they will go to another place which is not as fantastic as Jannah (heaven), but on the whole that is a good place and actually that is a better than this world.

- My initial question is, is it a fact that they go to another place?
- Secondly, if so, where is that place and what is its name?

(**Note**: I am looking for authentic tradition(s) regarding this matter from Shi'a view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is often confusion between "heaven" and "paradise".
Paradise is a place where good people get to stay after the final day of judgement. Until then notable people are distributed among the seven heavens, seventh being the nearest to earth.

I tried searching a lot but couldn't find exactly in which numbered heaven are those children right now.

I've heard that during the Mi'raj of prophet (peace be upon him) he encountered some prophet (peace be upon him) (don't know exactly who was that) teaching small children who died before puberty.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: Nice reply @wiser, well done. of course ur reply would be nicer by mentioning some source(s). Good luck.

Comment: God willing I'll survey it today. Besides, well done for mentioning the difference between paradise and heaven. Since perhaps there are many people who don't know their difference. To be honest I didn't know their difference exactly (as 2 English words which both of them mean Jannah).

Comment: Could you quote that Hadith please?